# SQL Server Foreign Key "On Delete Set Null " constraint not working

Tags: null, constraints, sql-server-express, foreign-key-relationship, cascading-deletes

I am using sql server express 2008 with mmse. 
i have set up a foreign key constraint between to tables and set the on delete constraint to "set null". 
however it does no seem to enforce the constraint and i am left with the ID in the field of the now deleted row.

here is a small [screen sho](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMsO4.png)t of how i have it set up

where could i be going wrong?

[Table 1](http://codepaste.net/enpzpj) [Table 2](http://codepaste.net/2ewbg3)

Comment: Have you only just set this up? If so did you press save in SSMS? It seems the FK constraint must be disabled or not present at all if it leaves you with an orphaned row. Otherwise can you script out full DDL for both tables involved?

Comment: Yeah. I've saved and also use VStudio and the schema has passed over to the Designer. but still its not working. whether i do a delete in SSMS or programatically through VStudio.

Comment: Can you script out the DDL for both tables (including the FK definition) and add it to your question?

Comment: Thanks. Tables now added to the Post

Comment: None of the above links (screen shot or the two code snippets) work any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DDL you posted works fine for me.

```
declare @id int;
INSERT INTO DeliveryAreas(Description,Rate) VALUES ('To Delete', 100)
set @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO Customer(FName,DeliveryAreaID) VALUES ('Test',@id)
SELECT ID,FName,DeliveryAreaID FROM Customer
DELETE FROM DeliveryAreas WHERE ID=@id
SELECT ID,FName,DeliveryAreaID FROM Customer
```

Returns

```
ID          FName                          DeliveryAreaID
----------- ------------------------------ --------------
1           Test                           3


ID          FName                          DeliveryAreaID
----------- ------------------------------ --------------
1           Test                           NULL
```

Can you just double check the enabled status your end?

```
SELECT is_disabled,* FROM sys.foreign_keys where name='FK_Customer_DeliveryAreas'
```

Comment: Thanks that was great. it seems to work perfect now. i have no idea what was the problem previously. i didn't change anything, but thanks for the help.